# Strange prolem with counting block height in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Looks like the simple task, but bring me to the dead end.
I have the HTML list with the different content Need to make the equal height.

My code:

```
 function tab_info_height(){

    var maxHeight = 0;
    alert(maxHeight + " - null px. Set to zero.") // Cheching for zero

    $(".tabs-container .tabs-info li").each(function(maxHeight){

      if(maxHeight < $(this).height()){
        var maxHeight = $(this).height();
        alert(maxHeight);
        alert("Good!");
      }else{
        alert("No!");
      }

    });
  }
```

There are many alerts fot step by step check. So I got the following numbers during execitual: 32, 64, 96 and **48** again. Why I got it. Why not 96 there?
I already search the solution only, but I cannot understand where is my mistake.

Comment: can you please add your html and css ?

Comment: Why is this being downvoted so much?  It clearly states the problem and enough code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're shadowing your `maxHeight` variable with a function argument (see the `****` comments):

```
function tab_info_height() {

    var maxHeight = 0;
    //  ^-------------------- **** Here's the variable
    alert(maxHeight + " - null px. Set to zero.") // Cheching for zero

    $(".tabs-container .tabs-info li").each(function(maxHeight) {
        // **** Here's the argument ---------------------^

        if (maxHeight < $(this).height()) {
            var maxHeight = $(this).height();
            //  ^--------------------- **** Also get rid of this `var`
            alert(maxHeight);
            alert("Good!");
        } else {
            alert("No!");
        }

    });
}
```

So within your function, you're using the argument, not the variable. As you don't need or want the argument, remove it. Also, remove the `var` from the `var maxHeight = $(this).height();` line; once you remove the argument, that `var` will continue to cause shadowing.

So minimal changes:

```
function tab_info_height() {

    var maxHeight = 0;
    alert(maxHeight + " - null px. Set to zero.") // Cheching for zero

    $(".tabs-container .tabs-info li").each(function() {

        if (maxHeight < $(this).height()) {
            maxHeight = $(this).height();
            alert(maxHeight);
            alert("Good!");
        } else {
            alert("No!");
        }

    });
}
```

Unless you actually need the `if/else`, though, use `Math.max`:

```
function tab_info_height() {

    var maxHeight = 0;

    $(".tabs-container .tabs-info li").each(function() {
        maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, $(this).height());
    });
}
```

If you *do* need the `if/else`, consider storing the result of `$(this).height()` in a variable so you're not doing it twice, as both `$(this)` and `.height()` have to do work.

You probably also want a return statement at the end of the function, e.g.:

```
return maxHeight;
```

If you want to take brevity to an extreme, and you have ES5 functions available (because the browser provides them, or you're using a polyfill), you can really go to town:

```
var reduce = Array.prototype.reduce;
function tab_info_height() {
    return reduce.call($(".tabs-container .tabs-info li"), function(max, el) {
          return Math.max(max, $(el).height());
    }, 0);
}
```

```js
var reduce = Array.prototype.reduce;
function tab_info_height() {
  return reduce.call($(".tabs-container .tabs-info li"), function(max, el) {
    return Math.max(max, $(el).height());
  }, 0);
}

$("<p>").html("Max: " + tab_info_height()).appendTo(document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs-container">
  <ul class="tabs-info">
    <li>I'm shorter than the other one</li>
    <li>I'm taller<br>than the other one</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are passing `maxHeight` into the function so it is overwriting your global: `function(maxHeight)`.

By setting it in the function you are setting it to the `index` of your `li`.

Try this:

```
$(".tabs-container .tabs-info li").each(function(index){
    if(maxHeight < $(this).height()){
        maxHeight = $(this).height();
        alert(maxHeight);
        alert("Good!");
     }else{
        alert("No!");
     }
});
```

[See this for more information on the each loop](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)